# XDocument throws away SIGNIFICANT whitespace inside tags

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, whitespace

Am I missing something relevant in the XML spec? Surely spaces INSIDE tags should be preserved?

```
string xml = @"

<xml>
    <text> </text>
</xml>                ";

//succeeds, but keeps unwanted insignificant whitespace
Assert.AreEqual(XDocument.Parse(xml, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace)
                         .Root.Element("text").Value, " ");

//fails
Assert.AreEqual(XDocument.Parse(xml)
                         .Root.Element("text").Value, " ");
```

Comment: Some observations: single line with just spaces in value `var xml = "<xml><text> </text></xml>";`  will also fai, it seems **only** white spaces in value means that value is `""`. Adding **any** non-white space character into the value will preserve white spaces.

Comment: As mentioned by Sinatr above, [white space](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#sec-white-space) is considered significant if there is at least one non-white-space character in the element's [text content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#syntax).  There is no distinction between newline and space characters in determining whether whitespace is "significant" -- both are whitespace.

Comment: As a workaround, you could add `xml:space="preserve"` to `<text>` like so: `<text xml:space="preserve"> </text>`, or you could embed the value of `<text>` in a CDATA section: `<text><![CDATA[ ]]></text>`.  Demo fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ViT15s.  Do either of those workarounds answer your question?